# Unable to fetch from another fork of same repo github

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo from say user1/repo1 to me/repo1.

Another user has forked the same repo from user1/repo1 to user2/repo1.

I have read access to both repo. I can confirm because i can open the code in browser. I have cloned the forked version of my repo to local.

Now i want to fetch changes from user2/repo1/branchA.
user2/repo was not in my remote list. So i added it using

```
git remote add https://github.com/user2/repo1.git
```

Verified using

```
git remote -v
```

and it shows the  remote.Now when i am trying to fetch using

```
git fetch user2 
git fetch user2 branchA
git fetch user2/branchA
```

nothing works and i get fatal: repo not found

Also tried cloning the repo directly from link user2/repo1 to local using

```
git clone https://github.com/user2/repo1.git
```

but unable to do so.
Github wont allow me to create a fork of another fork as i already have forked one version of the repo.

Already looked answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971049/what-does-the-git-error-remote-repository-not-found-mean

https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/

and various others as i am searching this from 4-5 hours.

Comment: From what you've described, things should be working.  Can you clone `user2/repo1` to you local machine?

Comment: @heavyd no i am unable to clone it using https , "git clone https://github.com/user2/repo1.git"

Comment: Are you sure the repo exists?  Is it a private repo?  If so, you would need to authenticate your git client.

Comment: yes it exists and its private repo. my git client is authenticated using my account

Comment: What have you done to authenticate your git client?  The problem you are describing sounds like an authentication problem.

Comment: authenticaton is ssh based. generating key and adding it to github acount. its not authentication problem as the repo got cloned via ssh

Comment: You can't use SSH authentication with an `http://` repository, you must use either a [SSH repository URL](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) or if you must use HTTP you can generate a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).